# Karma jasmine test fails when running on PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

My javascript tests using are passing when I use the Karma Chrome Launcher, however they fail when I use the PhantomJS browser. This codebase is also using ES6 and babel, but I don't think that's the problem as all my ES6 code in other modules aren't breaking.

I'm having the most trouble with understanding the stack trace I'm getting for my 3 failing tests. The error notes `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ',' (line 2)
    Function@[native code]`. I don't know what to do with that or how to debug with a breakpoint since it's talking about native code.  What I tried is below.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) paymentForm completes payment, displays thank you FAILED
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ',' (line 2)
    Function@[native code]
    compile@bower_components/angular/angular.js:14539:27
    parse@bower_components/angular/angular.js:15422:36
    $parse@bower_components/angular/angular.js:15587:44
    $watch@bower_components/angular/angular.js:16800:25
    link@bower_components/angular/angular.js:24221:21
    bower_components/angular/angular.js:1266:23
    invokeLinkFn@bower_components/angular/angular.js:9757:15
    nodeLinkFn@bower_components/angular/angular.js:9156:23
    compositeLinkFn@bower_components/angular/angular.js:8459:23
    nodeLinkFn@bower_components/angular/angular.js:9151:35
    bower_components/angular/angular.js:9496:36
    processQueue@bower_components/angular/angular.js:16104:30
    bower_components/angular/angular.js:16120:39
    $eval@bower_components/angular/angular.js:17378:28
    $digest@bower_components/angular/angular.js:17191:36
    flush@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1791:45
    src/app/payment/payment.directive.spec.js:163:25
```

**What I attempted:**

- changed between v4.2.6 and 6.10.2 and reinstalled the packages below
- upgraded the npm packages:

  - karma 0.12.31 -> 1.3.0,
  - karma-phantomjs-launcher 1.0.0 -> 1.04 (latest)
    no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was breaking my code was a duplicate key in my angular template. Wow. Ahh the joys of being a web developer. Oddly my old code didn't break in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.

```
<div
  class="slds-spinner"
  ng-class="{
    'slds-spinner--small': size === 'small',
    'slds-spinner--small': size === 'medium' || !size,
    'slds-spinner--large': size === 'large',
    'slds-spinner--inverse': inverse === 'true'
  }"
  aria-hidden="false"
  role="alert">

  <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
  <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
</div>
```

When I changed it to this:

```
<!-- No more dupe keys -->
<div
  class="slds-spinner"
  ng-class="{
    'slds-spinner--small': size === 'small' || !size,
    'slds-spinner--medium': size === 'medium',
    'slds-spinner--large': size === 'large',
    'slds-spinner--inverse': inverse === 'true'
  }"
  aria-hidden="false"
  role="alert">

  <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
  <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
</div>
```